# Excluir linhas de um Dataframe a partir de uma lista de strings em python

Tags: python, pandas

Estou com Um DataFrame para análise da Covid-19 e Quando puxo a maior quantidade de casos ou mortes, me retornam os continentes e eu gostaria de excluir apenas as entradas onde os continentes aparecem, deixar apenas os países.

Por exemplo, criei essa lista e então fui capaz de puxar as entradas sem os continentes.

```
continentes = ['Europe', 'Asia', 'North America', 'South America', 'Oceania', 'Africa', 'European Union']

df.loc[~df.location.isin(continentes)][df.date == '2021-04-27'].sort_values(by='total_cases', ascending=False)
```

Porém, quando vou criar um gráfico de barras e uso esse comando

```
df.loc[df.date == '2021-04-27', ['location', 'total_deaths']].sort_values(by="total_deaths", ascending=False)[0:6]
```

É retornado os valores dos continentes, por isso gostaria de excluir essas entradas, alguns comandos que tentei não resolveram ou deram erro, por exemplo:

```
df.drop(df[df.location == 'Europe', 'North America', 'Asia', 'Oceania', 'South America', 'Africa', 'European Union'].index)

df.drop(df[df.location == continentes].index)
```

Vou tentar reproduzir quando dou o comando para localizar os países com mais mortes e sua localização

```
location        total_deaths        

world           3134956.0
europe          1007023.0
north america   843246.0
european union  682014.0
south america   658283.0
```

Agradeço muito se alguém conseguir me ajudar!!!

Comment: Você pode atualizar o post com um pedaço do seu dataframe para que possamos reproduzir o problema? Em tempo, não cole a imagem.

Comment: atualizei o post, precisa ser uma representação do dataframe todo? ou apenas essa basta? pois é um dataframe com 59 colunas kkkkkkk bem grande

Comment: Acredito que isso resolva: `df = df.drop(df[df['location'].isin(continentes)].index)`

Comment: obrigado!! valeu demais Paulo